# What's the significance of Hezekiah praying facing the wall?

Tags: isaiah

> Isaiah 38:1 In those days Hezekiah became ill and was at the point of death. The prophet Isaiah son of Amoz went to him and said, “This is what the Lord says: Put your house in order, because you are going to die; you will not recover.”
> 2Hezekiah turned his **face to the wall** and prayed to the Lord, 3“Remember, Lord, how I have walked before you faithfully and with wholehearted devotion and have done what is good in your eyes.” And Hezekiah wept bitterly.

What wall was this? Is there a significance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Hezekiah received this very bad news, there would have been, not only the prophet but sundry other court officials in the room as well such as his personal physician, court secretary, valet, etc.  The act of turning one's face to the wall immediately beside the couch on which the sick man lay was to provide privacy and probably as a signal to those present that he wish to be alone.

Recall that Hezekiah was very ill and probably could not get up to go to another room to pray.

This is widely recognized - note Ellicott's comments:

> (2) Turned his face toward the wall . . .—The royal couch was in the
> corner, as the Eastern place of honour, the face turned to it, as
> seeking privacy and avoiding the gaze of men. (Comp. Ahab in 1Kings
> 21:4.)

Barnes notes:

> Then Hezekiah turned his face toward the wall - The wall of the room
> in which he was lying He was probably lying on a couch next the wall
> of his room. Eastern houses usually have such couches or ottomans
> running along on the sides of the room on which they recline, and on
> which they lie when they are sick. Hezekiah probably turned his face
> to the wall in order that his emotion and his tears might not be seen
> by the bystanders, or in order that he might compose himself the
> better for devotion. His prayer he wished, doubtless, to be as secret
> as possible.

Cambridge commentary:

> 2. turned his face toward the wall] (cf. 1 Kings 21:4) an instinctive expression of the feeling that he was alone with God in this bitter
>    moment.

Pulpit commentary:

> Verse 2. - Hezekiah turned his face toward the wall. The action
> resembles that of Ahab (1 Kings 21:4); but the spirit is wholly
> different. Ahab turned away in sullenness, Hezekiah that he might pray
> undisturbed Beds seem to have been placed in the corners of rooms,
> with the head against one wall of the room, and one side against
> another.